# Ranking Data Comparison

Tags: spss, experiment-design, ranking, rating

I'm currently analyzing my experimental data and I have a question about comparing two variables. 
In the experiment I have a question which asks respondents to rank a set of pictures based on their preference from first to last (1 to 6 ranking). The respondents are then presented with some information (as condition) and need to assess again the pictures they were presented with initially. This time however they need to rate every picture on an evaluation scale from 1 to 7. 
My question now is whether I can compare the ranking and rating score of the pictures in order to see whether the provided information had any effect on the evaluation of the pictures. Is that possible, any suggestions??

Many thansk!

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in use (more than in development), you should give a try to [rankade](https://rankade.com), our ranking system. Rankade is free and easy to use, it can manage small to large playing groups (composed by players or 'items', as per your needs), and it features rankings, stats, and more.

Ghosts' feature allows you to create a group without any account but your. Rankade's algorithm can manage, within different scopes, any kind of match. Due to faction structure, you can record outputs for both your needs. In first case, simply rank factions (e.g. A > B > C > D > E > F) *based on their preferences*, while in the second use ties for same score (e.g. A,7 = C,7 > B,5 > C,4 = E,4 > F,2 > D,1) in your *evaluation scale*.